# difference between 'time python' and 'time python3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

what is the difference between using 'time python' and 'time python3' to check the execution time?

When I use `time python test.py` I get:

```
zsh: command not found: python
python test.py  0.00s user 0.00s system 56% cpu 0.003 total
```

whereas when I use `time python3 test.py` I get:

```
python3 test.py  0.05s user 0.01s system 90% cpu 0.064 total
```

Comment: What does `type python` say?

Comment: Although there's generally no reason to assume `python` would be a Python 2 interpreter; virtual environments tend to use `python` as a link to whatever Python was used to create the virtual environment.

Comment: `time` is a `zsh` command modifier; it doesn't care *what* command is being timed, but simply times whatever is requested. The error message is independent of `time`, because you simply don't have `python` in your search path.

Comment: @Jens The path to *python* isn't reliant on a particular version. For example, on my machine I set *python* as an alias for *python3* which is currently 3.12.1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The error is saying you don't have a command called `python`, so the answer to the question is then "`time python` doesn't work"; is that not obvious? You can [edit] if you need to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between time python and time python3 lies in the interpreter used to run your script. Here's a breakdown:

time python:
Attempts to run the script using the default Python interpreter on your system.

This can be problematic because:

- Multiple Python versions might be installed: If both Python 2 and 3
  are available, python might default to the older, slower Python 2,
  leading to inaccurate timing results.
- Default behavior can vary: Depending on your system configuration,
  the default interpreter might not be what you expect.

time python3:
Explicitly specifies the Python 3 interpreter, ensuring your script runs with the desired version.

This guarantees:

- Accurate timing: You're measuring the performance of your script
  using the correct Python version.
- Improved performance: Python 3    offers significant performance
  improvements over Python 2, so you'll    likely see faster execution
  times.

In your example, the difference in execution times observed with time python and time python3 likely reflects the use of two different Python versions. Python 2 being significantly slower explains the longer execution time with time python.

Therefore, for professional contexts and accurate timing, it's always recommended to use time python3 to explicitly specify the Python 3 interpreter and ensure consistent, representative results.